# How to get actions from another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How to get actions from another controller without `[self presentModalViewController: ololo animated:YES];`?
Can I use just

```
Tutorial *ololo = [[Tutorial alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:ololo.view];
```

?

Right now with this code I get EXC BAD ACCESS error, when I'm trying to press button on new view.

May it will be easier to create 2 subclasses of UIView with their own XIBs, or may be I can use NavigateController without navigation bar?

PS Yes, I have Tutorial.h, Tutorial.m, Tutorial.xib. In XIB file there are 2 views (portrait and landscape).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Tutorial object extends UIViewController

`@interface Tutorial : UIViewController {`

Also make sure that you have a Tutorial.xib file, which has a view, and the outlet from the view it's linked with the one from the viewcontroller.

as a best practice try this :

```
Tutorial *ololo = [[[Tutorial alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tutorial" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:ololo.view];
```

Also, if you need 2 views in the same view controller, you can just add 2 views in IB, add an outlet to the second one, and add it as a subview of the main one :

```
[self.view addSubview:secondView]
```

this way, both of them are managed by the same viewcontroller, and you can add actions in the same view controller.

Comment: And you are calling this from an other viewController ?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it from main viewController, not from Tutorial view controller.
And I use ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
try to pass xibf file name as parameter to initWithNibName,ekse just use int method.hope it wont crash

Comment: `Tutorial *ololo = [[Tutorial alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tutorial" bundle:nil];`
I already tried this. Same problem.

Comment: Have u created xib file named tutorial?